# Large file regex and Memory Mapped File boundary

Tags: regex, windows, mfc, memory-mapped-files

I want to regex match through large file.
It is text file. To show the file on GUI, I use memory mapped file and view (Windows/MFC).
The problem when I want to search(regex) whole text, I cannot match the mapped view's boundary correctly (I haven't tried it yet but I think it cannot be matched).
Say, I have a text "aab|bcc" where "|" is the mapped view's boundary.
I want to match "bb". I'm using CAtlRegex.
Theoretically, it should be possible if I write regex engine that supports such boundary problem (but I don't want to do it...).

Is there any good solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

As as long as you know how long the largest matching string is, it should work in this way. ANd I guess that this largest size is les than dwAllocationGranularity.

When you searched up to position x. Just define the next segment for the search starting from x-dwAllocationGranularity.

So the overhead is to search dwAllocationGranularity bytes twice.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is one possible solution.  I don't know the maximum matching length but it can be specification.

Comment: As long as it is below dwAllocationGranularity my solution should work.